# Export QGIS To Oracle Loderfiles

Tags: qgis

A customer receives data for Oracle, always as Oracle Loderfiles (Oracle object model). This is an SQL export in a folder structure (see example export/picture) which can then be read directly into any Oracle via the command prompt ("Import  /  @ "). The function is available in GeoMedia.

Example Export

[image]

This is a practical feature that I haven't found in QGIS yet.

Is there such a function or a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

See the GDAL driver page https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oci.html. There is some support for the loader files if you use the layer creation option (`-lco`)

> **LOADER_FILE**:
>
> If this option is set, all feature information will be
> written to a file suitable for use with SQL*Loader instead of inserted
> directly in the database. The layer itself is still created in the
> database immediately. The SQL*Loader support is experimental, and
> generally MULTI_LOAD enabled mode should be used instead when trying
> for optimal load performance.

At least you can get all the INSERT statements into a text file. Have a try and check if the generated SQL contains also the CREATE TABLE statements.